# Independent sets with few neighbours

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

*[Posted this first at math stackexchange, but it probably fits better here.]*

I am looking for references about the following problem.

> Given a (connected) bipartite graph $G$, find an independent set $M$ minimizing the ratio $|\partial M|/|M|$.

Here, $\partial M$ denotes the set of neighbours of $M$.
An independent set is a set $M$ of vertices such that $(\partial M)\cap M = \emptyset$.

More specifically, I am looking for information about the class of bipartite <del>graphs</del> *trees* $G= (A\,\dot{\cup}\, B \,, E)$ for which $A$ is *the unique solution* to the problem above.

Examples of such graphs include lines with an odd number of vertices, or, more generally, trees in which every $b\in B$ has degree two.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4461624/independent-sets-with-few-neighbours

Comment: A trivial note: If $M$ is an optimal independent set, then one of $M\cap A$ and $M\cap B$ is also such. So, for the specific question, it suffices to check separately subsets of $A$ and $B$ only.

Comment: Another observation: the ‘specific’ condition is satisfied iff $|B|<|A|$, and $|\partial B’|>\frac{|A|}{|B|}\cdot |B’|$ for every$\varnothing\neq B’\subsetneq B$.

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov: Indeed so (but it should be $|\partial A'| > \frac{|B|}{|A|}\cdot |A'|$ for $\emptyset \ne A'\subsetneq A$ in your second comment). I have managed to prove some things about these graphs (e.g., they must be acyclic), but I'm not graph theorist and don't know the literature on the subject, so I'm afraid that I'm spending time on stuff that is already known...

Comment: @BikD In your formula, there should be a $<$ sogn instead of $>$; and I meant exactly what I meant, that was the reason of putting that into a comment. As for the second part of your comment --- I don't understand acyclicity, as a complete bipartite graph  (with parts of different size) firs into the condition...

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov: If $A=M$ is the unique solution to the problem of minimising the ratio $|\partial M|/|M|$, then $\frac{|\partial M|}{|M|} > \frac{|\partial A|}{|A|} = \frac{|B|}{|A|}$ for any independent set $M$, including when $M=A'\subset A$. So I think that my inequality is correct.
The inequality $\frac{|\partial B'|}{|B'|} > \frac{|\partial A|}{|A|}$ is not sufficient. Consider the Dynkin graph of type $D_6$, with $A$ containing the leaves. Then any $\emptyset\ne B'\subsetneq B$ is a singleton, and $|\partial B'|\ge 2 > 2/4 = |B|/|A|$. But the condition is not satisfied for this graph.

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov You are right about the acyclicity. Actually, the general definition of the graphs I'm interested in is different from what I wrote, and _that definition_ implies that the graph is acyclic. The characterisation given in the question works for trees only. My wrong. I will correct this in the question.